# How to show paths for auto imports with neovim nvim-cmp

Tags: autocomplete, neovim

Using neovim with nvim-cmp in ecmascript/typescript I want the menu to show 2 things that are not there by default.

1. If it's a local module, show the path.
2. If it's an import from a library, show the library name. (preferably in different color/font/icon than import from local component).

The [docs](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/wiki) shows a few examples of how to setup icons, but not how to show paths.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve something similar by adding these lines in the `format` function while calling nvim-cmp's setup:

```
  if entry.completion_item.detail ~= nil and entry.completion_item.detail ~= "" then
    vim_item.menu = entry.completion_item.detail
  else
    vim_item.menu = ({
      nvim_lsp = "[LSP]",
      luasnip = "[Snippet]",
      buffer = "[Buffer]",
      path = "[Path]",
    })[entry.source.name]
  end
```

result:

[image]